# Display text as values in pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a dataset sample shown below:

```
Name    Area    Term        Score
AA      SW      Summer      A
AB      NW      Spring      B
AC      SW      Winter      D
AD      NW      Spring      C
```

I need to display a pivot table with text as values the table should follow the below

```
        Summer     Spring     Winter
A       AA         
B                  AB
C                  AD
D                             AC
```

Inside the grid should display the Name(s) of each person who achieves the respective grade in a specific for example Name "AA" would appear in the first cell between Grade A and Summer term.

I have found many examples online but nothing specifically for what I need. I am using excel version 2010.

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do it is

1. set up a pivot table on a new tab with
   rows - score, name
   columns - term
   value - count of name
2. to the right set h5=IF(C5>0,$B5,"")
3. copy that to your range
4. hide the desired columns of the pivot table

there's more complicated ways, but that's the easiest

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, this is exactly what I need. I need to be able to display more than one name in the cell giving the grid i shared above is it possible to have it like that rather than a name per cell? Also is it possible to do it with the pivot table as I need to use slicers on that pivot table to allow the user to filter on specific options